# android 5.0 arm emulator doesn't work

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop

i have a PC with "Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz × 2 " CPU and 2 GB of Ram and Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit installed. now i am trying to lunch an android 5.0 arm emulator but it keeps showing the android screen for hours and hours and doesn't start .

```
Ram Size=1536 MB
internal storage : 1024M
VM heap Size=64
API 21
```

here is a screen shot:[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try with gpu acceleration on (if you don't have one which is well supported under Linux, I suggest getting one ASAP).

Comment: Secondly, I think the requirements for emulation are higher than your setup (I remember reading 4gb?)

Answer (score 2):

Android Emulator always takes time, try to test in Android Phone or use Genymotion

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong with your computer or configuration. API system images after 19 takes a lot of toll on computer and usually take time to start or never start. try genemotion or Bluestack to run your application